# vim keeps starting in vimdiff mode for some files

Tags: vim, vimdiff

Somehow `vim` remembers that I did `vimdiff` on certain files and keeps opening them in the `vimdiff` mode. What that means is that when I open that same file again I get a grey bar displayed on the left (like the `foldcolumn`) but worse when I try to add another file with `:sp anotherfile.txt` it comes up in a full on diff mode - interlocked, diff highlighted, etc.

It's completely as if I opened the first file with `vimdiff somefile.txt`, yet I didn't. I opened it with `vim somefile.txt` and it still behaves like `vimdiff`, only because in the past I opened it with `vimdiff`. It's very annoying.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found it. I added these to my `/.vimrc` a couple weeks ago:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

Now whenever I used `vimdiff` it created a *vimdiff view* for the particular file and then reloaded it the next time I opened the file.

That was quite unintended for `vimdiff`. I'll have to have a look how to activate `mkview` only for plain vim and not for vimdiff.

Comment: Something like `autocmd BufWinEnter *.* if &diff != 'diff' | silent loadview | endif`